# UISplitViewControllerのDetailViewControllerでnavigationBarが透明にならない。

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcodeの雛形のMaster-Detailを使って作ったプロジェクトのDetailViewControllerで、

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // ナビゲーションを透明にする処理
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

としてもnavigationBarが透明になりません。

```
navBar?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

は、反応して「＜」ボタンが赤くなります。

更に
上のコードをMaster側に書いても、
透明になりません。

どうすれば透明にできますか？

Answer (score 1):

これは、Show Detail Segue の挙動がどういうものなのかを理解する必要があります。

Master と Detail で画面が分かれる場合には、Detail の `UINavigationController` は使われません。Master の `UINavigationController` の ViewController スタックの先頭を置き換えます。

iPhone 6S Plus の Landscape や iPad で確認すれば透明になっているのが分かると思います。

[image: 透明ですよね]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。「ViewController スタックの先頭を置き換える」とは具体的にどのようには書けばいいのでしょうか？

Comment: @forest それは Show Detail Segue が自動的に行っていることですので、ユーザが意識して書く必要はありません。Master と Detail が一画面に収まらない場合には、Master 側の `UINavigationBar` を透明にする必要があります。